# freeRTOS linking process: multiple definition of `_start'

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, embedded, freertos

I am trying to compile freeRTOS for raspberry pi 2. Those are the commands I tried so far:

1. arm-none-eabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4
   -mfloat-abi=hard test.c -o test.o
2. arm-none-eabi-as -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4
       -mfloat-abi=hard startup.s -o startup.o
3. arm-none-eabi-ld test.o startup.o -static -Map kernel7.map -o
       target.elf -T raspberrypi.ld

The two upper ones do work fine. However the last one doesn't, it gives me the following error:

startup.o: In function `_start':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of`_start'
test.o::(.text+0x6c): first defined here
startup.o: In function `swi_handler':
(.init+0x28): undefined reference to`vPortYieldProcessor'
startup.o: In function `irq_handler':
(.init+0x38): undefined reference to`vFreeRTOS_ISR'
startup.o: In function `zero_loop':
(.init+0xcc): undefined reference to`rpi_cpu_irq_disable'

This is the corresponding code:

---

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void exit(int code)
{
    while(1)
        ;
}

int main(void)
{

    return 0;
}
```

---

startup.s:

```
.extern system_init
.extern __bss_start
.extern __bss_end
.extern vFreeRTOS_ISR
.extern vPortYieldProcessor
.extern rpi_cpu_irq_disable
.extern main
    .section .init
    .globl _start
;; 
_start:
    ;@ All the following instruction should be read as:
    ;@ Load the address at symbol into the program counter.

    ldr pc,reset_handler        ;@  Processor Reset handler         -- we will have to force this on the raspi!
    ;@ Because this is the first instruction executed, of cause it causes an immediate branch into reset!

    ldr pc,undefined_handler    ;@  Undefined instruction handler   -- processors that don't have thumb can emulate thumb!
    ldr pc,swi_handler          ;@  Software interrupt / TRAP (SVC) -- system SVC handler for switching to kernel mode.
    ldr pc,prefetch_handler     ;@  Prefetch/abort handler.
    ldr pc,data_handler         ;@  Data abort handler/
    ldr pc,unused_handler       ;@  -- Historical from 26-bit addressing ARMs -- was invalid address handler.
    ldr pc,irq_handler          ;@  IRQ handler
    ldr pc,fiq_handler          ;@  Fast interrupt handler.

    ;@ Here we create an exception address table! This means that reset/hang/irq can be absolute addresses
reset_handler:      .word reset
undefined_handler:  .word undefined_instruction
swi_handler:        .word vPortYieldProcessor
prefetch_handler:   .word prefetch_abort
data_handler:       .word data_abort
unused_handler:     .word unused
irq_handler:        .word vFreeRTOS_ISR
fiq_handler:        .word fiq

reset:
    /* Disable IRQ & FIQ */
    cpsid if

    /* Check for HYP mode */
    mrs r0, cpsr_all
    and r0, r0, #0x1F
    mov r8, #0x1A
    cmp r0, r8
    beq overHyped
    b continueBoot

overHyped: /* Get out of HYP mode */
    ldr r1, =continueBoot
    msr ELR_hyp, r1
    mrs r1, cpsr_all
    and r1, r1, #0x1f   ;@ CPSR_MODE_MASK
    orr r1, r1, #0x13   ;@ CPSR_MODE_SUPERVISOR
    msr SPSR_hyp, r1
    eret

continueBoot:
    ;@  In the reset handler, we need to copy our interrupt vector table to 0x0000, its currently at 0x8000

    mov r0,#0x8000                              ;@ Store the source pointer
    mov r1,#0x0000                              ;@ Store the destination pointer.

    ;@  Here we copy the branching instructions
    ldmia r0!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}         ;@ Load multiple values from indexed address.       ; Auto-increment R0
    stmia r1!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}         ;@ Store multiple values from the indexed address.  ; Auto-increment R1

    ;@  So the branches get the correct address we also need to copy our vector table!
    ldmia r0!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}         ;@ Load from 4*n of regs (8) as R0 is now incremented.
    stmia r1!,{r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9}         ;@ Store this extra set of data.


    ;@  Set up the various STACK pointers for different CPU modes
    ;@ (PSR_IRQ_MODE|PSR_FIQ_DIS|PSR_IRQ_DIS)
    mov r0,#0xD2
    msr cpsr_c,r0
    mov sp,#0x8000

    ;@ (PSR_FIQ_MODE|PSR_FIQ_DIS|PSR_IRQ_DIS)
    mov r0,#0xD1
    msr cpsr_c,r0
    mov sp,#0x4000

    ;@ (PSR_SVC_MODE|PSR_FIQ_DIS|PSR_IRQ_DIS)
    mov r0,#0xD3
    msr cpsr_c,r0
    mov sp,#0x8000000

    ldr r0, =__bss_start
    ldr r1, =__bss_end

    mov r2, #0

zero_loop:
    cmp     r0,r1
    it      lt
    strlt   r2,[r0], #4
    blt     zero_loop

    bl      rpi_cpu_irq_disable


    ;@  mov sp,#0x1000000
    b main                                  ;@ We're ready?? Lets start main execution!
    .section .text

undefined_instruction:
    b undefined_instruction

prefetch_abort:
    b prefetch_abort

data_abort:
    b data_abort

unused:
    b unused

fiq:
    b fiq

hang:
    b hang

.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
```

---

raspberrypi.ld:

```
/**
 * BlueThunder Linker Script for the raspberry Pi!
 *
 *
 *
 **/
MEMORY
{
    RESERVED    (r) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 32K
    INIT_RAM    (rwx)   : ORIGIN = 0x00008000, LENGTH = 32K
    RAM     (rwx)   : ORIGIN = 0x00010000, LENGTH = 128M
}

ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
    /*
     * Our init section allows us to place the bootstrap code at address 0x8000
     *
     * This is where the Graphics processor forces the ARM to start execution.
     * However the interrupt vector code remains at 0x0000, and so we must copy the correct
     * branch instructions to 0x0000 - 0x001C in order to get the processor to handle interrupts.
     *
     */
    .init : {
        KEEP(*(.init))
    } > INIT_RAM = 0

    .module_entries : {
        __module_entries_start = .;
        KEEP(*(.module_entries))
        KEEP(*(.module_entries.*))
        __module_entries_end = .;
        __module_entries_size = SIZEOF(.module_entries);
    } > INIT_RAM


    /**
     *  This is the main code section, it is essentially of unlimited size. (128Mb).
     *
     **/
    .text : {
        *(.text)
    } > RAM

    /*
    * Next we put the data.
    */
    .data : {
        *(.data)
    } > RAM

    .bss :
    {
        __bss_start = .;
        *(.bss)
        *(.bss.*)
        __bss_end = .;
    } > RAM

/*    
    __exidx_start = .;
    .ARM.exidx :
    {
        *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    } > RAM
    __exidx_end = .;
*/
    /**
     *  Place HEAP here???
     **/
    PROVIDE(__HEAP_START = __bss_end );
    /**
     *  Stack starts at the top of the RAM, and moves down!
     **/
    _estack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);
}
```

As you can see test.c doesn't contain an entry point called _start, neither does it have one in its assembly compiled form. Only startup.s does.

Any idea's about how I could solve my current issue?

**EDIT:** all the code if needed used can be found here:https://github.com/jameswalmsley/RaspberryPi-FreeRTOS

Comment: Off-site linking of your code is not acceptable - your question may live on SO far longer then the code exists on PasteBin.

Comment: The error message mentions `swi_handler` but your code does not show that so it is hard to tell if it is incomplete.  Equally the the undefined references refer to object code that you have not linked.

Comment: @Clifford swi_handler is supposed to be in startup.s but as you can see all the startup code is posted in the main post. The rest of the code can be found here: https://github.com/jameswalmsley/RaspberryPi-FreeRTOS
(will add the link in the main post)

Comment: You are not compiling/linking the FreeRTOS source code, so that code is not found...

Comment: @LPs well that is what I expected, tried and am having some difficulties with, could you help me by telling how I could do this is my third command?